# Talend Open Studio API

Tags: java, talend

Does Talend Open Studio have API for external access from other apps?
For example, I'd like to get the current project hierarchy and iterate over it.

Comment: This is all I know that exists ... https://api.eu.cloud.talend.com/tmc/swagger/swagger-ui.html ... which is TMC, so aside from that, I reckon you'd need to interrogate this file in GitHub (if you're using version control) to get your structure ... `<organisation>/<git-project>/blob/master/<talend-project>/poms/pom.xml`